# Angular js /Javascript keep track if how many times a process was called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, loops

I have my code below , doProcess was called many times depending on the myArray.length , Now the question is how 
can I keep track if how many times doProcess was called , ive tried using a counter but it does not seem to work out any idea?. Dont worry about the the doprocess was executed I already made it possible , i just want to track how many times doprocess was called.

```
doProcess(myArray, 0);
        function doProcess(myArray, index) {
            if (myArray.length === index) {
                return;
            }

            data["users"] = array
            data["random_code"] = myArray[index];

            QuestionaireService.share_questionaire(me, data).then(function (response) {

                if (response.status == "200") {
                    doProcess(myArray, ++index);
                    count++;
                }
            });

             console.log("count", count)

        }
```

Comment: Where does your `count` variable is declared? Outside of the function I guess? What is the output you get for the moment?

Comment: out the function bro

Comment: multiple counts , i just want the final count not count 1 ,count 2 count and so on

Comment: you are trying to increment `count` after `doProcess` call, it is never incremented because it is recursively calling function, call it before `doProcess` function call

Comment: put this `console.log("count", count)` outside of the function call

Comment: It logs count 1 , count 2 , count 3 , ..how can we just get the final count?

Comment: As @AbhinawKaushik said, put it outside of function doProcess

Comment: I did put it outside the function but the value is just 0 which is the value of count when its decleared

Comment: what is seem to be the issue?

Comment: this code is very fragile...rooms for multiple errors! and also you are not adding/removing the array elements passing back as is, so this recursion will keep on going unless the index doesn't throw an exception! and technically if we are handling all these parts then your method should be getting called equal to the length of the array...

Comment: so what would be your suggestion Sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the above communication. The requirement is just to print the `counter` only one time. Put the logging in the `if` condition.

Try this code.

```
var count = 0;

doProcess(myArray, 0);
    function doProcess(myArray, index) {
        if (myArray.length === index) {
            console.log("count", count)
            return;
        }

        data["users"] = array
        data["random_code"] = myArray[index];

        QuestionaireService.share_questionaire(me, data).then(function (response) {

            if (response.status == "200") {
                doProcess(myArray, ++index);
                count++;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Be careful, in case your `share_questionaire` doesn't respond with a 200 code, you won't ever have `myArray.length === index`, thus never print the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not trying to set a variable outside your function and then increment it inside :

```
  let counter = 0
  doProcess(myArray, 0);

  function doProcess(myArray, index) {
    counter += 1
    if (myArray.length === index) {
      return;
    }

    data["users"] = array
    data["random_code"] = myArray[index];

    QuestionaireService.share_questionaire(me, data)
    .then((response) => {

      if (response.status == "200") {
        doProcess(myArray, ++index);
        count++;
      }
    });

    console.log("count", count)

  }

  console.log("counter", counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is incremented well. But since you use a asynchronous call inside the `doProcess` function, the matter is when to print the counter?

So you have to print it when you are sur it won't increment more (so when you don't call doProcess() anymore).

Try something like:

```
doProcess(myArray, 0);
function doProcess(myArray, index) {
   count++;
   if (myArray.length === index) {
      // Need to print it too if the process is over
      console.log("count: ", count);
      return;
   }

   data["users"] = array
   data["random_code"] = myArray[index];

   QuestionaireService.share_questionaire(me, data).then(function (response) {

      if (response.status == "200") {
         doProcess(myArray, ++index);
      } else {
         // Here, you know you are in the last call of doProcess()
         console.log("count: ", count)
      }
   });
}
```